# Is there a way to authenticate a User in a React Native app with a PHP API, not using Facebook, firebase, etc.?

Tags: php, api, react-native

I've done some authentication before but I'm trying to authenticate using a backend PHP API. The loginUserFail method works but for some reason the loginUserSuccess does not get called...
This is the actions file that I have where I know I'm missing something.

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: `${GEN_ROOT_URL}user/${key}/${email}`,
  params: { password : password },
})
.then(results => {
    console.log(results.data.user);
    loginUserSuccess(dispatch, results)
  })
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    loginUserFail(dispatch)
  });
 };
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, results) => {
dispatch({
  type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  payload: results.data.user
});

 this.props.navigation.navigate('events');
};

const loginUserFail = (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL });
};
```

Comment: The `loginUserSuccess` method probably "isn't working" because your authentication is failing. What are you seeing in the console?

Comment: To answer your actual question, yes there is.

Comment: I'm messing around with it and it seems to throw the error whenever it gets to the 'this.props.navigation.navigate('events');' I'm thinking that the navigation isn't passed in and I'm not really sure where I can call it instead.